# Program crashes when tailing a file that rapidly updates

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, pyqt4, python-multithreading

Purpose of my program is to tail a file that is updated with possibly hundreds of lines of code every second, and append each line to a PyQt4 textbox in a GUI. When running my python code that tails a couple files and outputs each line to a QtPy textbox, my program crashes everytime a burst of lines are added to said files.

So far, I have tried implementing a wait timer `time.sleep(1)` within my while loop that appends each tailed line to the textbox. However, it appears I might be reaching a buffer overflow or cache limit because, while this works at how often the textbox is updated, when I get a burst of lines added to the tail file, my program still crashes.

```py
import sys, os, PyQt4, subprocess, time, threading
shouldRun = True
def tailFile():
    file1 = subprocess.Popen(['tail', '-F', 'FILENAME1', stdout=subprocess.PIPE, preecec_fn=os.setsid)
    poll1 = select.poll()
    poll1.register(file1.stdout)

    file2 = subprocess.Popen(['tail', '-F', 'FILENAME2', stdout=subprocess.PIPE, preecec_fn=os.setsid)
    poll2 = select.poll()
    poll2.register(file2.stdout)

    while shouldRun:
        textbox01.append(file1.stdout.readline())
        textbox02.append(file2.stdout.readline())
        #time.sleep(1)
    return


runTailing = threading.Thread(target = tailFile)
runTailing.start()
```

My only errors that show up are

```
QObject::connect: Cannot queue arguments of type 'QTextCursor'
(Make sure 'QTextCursor' is registered using qRegisterMetaType().)
ASSERT failure in QVector<T>::operator[]: "index out of range"
```

Comment: provide a [mre]

Comment: Even if you get no errors, your GUI will probably slow down each time you get a lot of lines to append. Your concept is wrong from the start. See my comment about it below.

Answer (score 0):

Because you do not provide an MRE it is difficult to point exactly where the error is and therefore give a solution based on your code. But from the error message it is observed that you try to add information to the GUI directly through the append method, and that is prohibited in Qt, in those cases the best option is to use signals.

My solution goes in another way since I propose to use QProcess that allows to execute tail without needing to create another thread notifying through signal of new information:

```py
import os
import sys

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui


class FileMonitor(QtCore.QObject):
    fileChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self, filename, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._filename = filename
        self._process = QtCore.QProcess(self)
        self._process.readyReadStandardOutput.connect(self._on_readyReadStandardOutput)

    @property
    def filename(self):
        return self._filename

    def start(self):
        self._process.start("tail", ["-F", self.filename])

    def _on_readyReadStandardOutput(self):
        text = self._process.readAllStandardOutput().data().decode()
        self.fileChanged.emit(text)


class Widget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.textbox01 = QtGui.QTextEdit(readOnly=True)
        self.textbox02 = QtGui.QTextEdit(readOnly=True)

        lay = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(self.textbox01)
        lay.addWidget(self.textbox02)

        current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
        filenames = [
            os.path.join(current_dir, "FILENAME1"),
            os.path.join(current_dir, "FILENAME2"),
        ]
        for filename, textbox in zip(filenames, (self.textbox01, self.textbox02)):
            monitor = FileMonitor(filename, self)
            monitor.fileChanged.connect(textbox.append)
            monitor.start()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I would advise you both to avoid using external programs at all. 'tail' or any other. Python can read files so, do it as it should be done. Use select and when data is available, read it, and split it into lines. And then, use the appropriate method to update the GUI element. If necessary, freeze the redrawing of the list, insert whole data again (from the start, not append), scroll it to the  end if this behaviour is what you want, and allow redraw again to make it change its values on the screen.

Comment: @Dalen Let's go in parts: 1) The use of tail is provided by the OP so I did not want to change that part, on the other hand I do not see it wrong to use an external program. 2) It seems that you do not know how Qt works so you think it can be frozen, because no, it already has an eventloop and a set of preset rules. If you have another solution that you consider relevant then I invite you to provide it.

Comment: I didn't say it's wrong to do it, just that you shouldn't when you do not must. The following example is absurd for the tail, but just to think it. Imagine your user suddenly uses the permissions to run tail for some reason, or the tail was updated and is not backward compatible any more. Your program depends on it and will crush or get wrong results. It's not likely that it will happen with tail, but using it is not the way for doing this.

Comment: Secondly, yes, I am rarely using QT, so I am not a specialist for its internals and/or special tricks. But any serious GUI framework can be made to temporarily ignore repaint of the element. If API doesn't support it directly, that doesn't mean it couldn't be done. If it couldn't, then I will never use QT again. Also, it was just a well meant advice. Take it or not, it's all the same to me.

Comment: 1) The same risk happens with python functions, but as it indicates with tail it would be a rare case since its task is specific so it could change the internal implementation but not the output it provides. 2) Unfortunately I will give you bad news that will make you not use Qt anymore: you cannot stop repainting, I have not worked with other frameworks.